# select color using onclick from a zoomed view

Tags: javascript, css

here is a color chart.i am willing to click on any one of them and using css scale property  make it larger for better view.then click on it again to select the desired color.i had no idea about it.so i tried to make a code .but it is not working as i expeted.in fact it is not working at all.how can i do that?

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #colorchart {
                position: fixed;
                width:250px;
                height:250px;
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                left:0px;
                top:350px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');
            table.addEventListener ('click', function (event) {
                var target = event.target||event.srcElement;
                if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
                    target.style.transform=scale(5, 5);
                    target.addEventListener ("click", function(event) {
                        var newTarget=event.target;
                        if (newTarget.tagName=='TD') {
                            alert(newTarget.bgColor);
                        }
                    }, false);
                }
            }, false);
        </script>
        <table id="colorchart"  >
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#FBEFEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBF2EF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBF5EF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBF8EF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBFBEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8FBEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5FBEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F2FBEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFFBEF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFFBF2"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFFBF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFFBF8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFFBFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFF8FB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFF5FB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFF2FB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#EFEFFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F2EFFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5EFFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8EFFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBEFFB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBEFF8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBEFF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FBEFF2"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FFFFFF"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8E6E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7F2E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F1F8E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E6F8E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F8E6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F8F1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0F2F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0E6F8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E6E0F8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#ECE0F8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F2E0F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8E0F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8E0F1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8E0EC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F8E0E6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FAFAFA"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#F6CECE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6D8CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6E3CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5ECCE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5F6CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#ECF6CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E3F6CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D8F6CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEF6CE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEF6D8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEF6E3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEF6EC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEF6F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEECF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CEE3F6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CED8F6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CECEF6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D8CEF6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E3CEF6"></td>
                <td bgColor="#ECCEF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6CEF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6CEEC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6CEE3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F6CED8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F2F2F2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5BCA9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F3E2A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E1F5A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BCF5A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9F5BC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9F5E1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9E2F3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9BCF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BCA9F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D0A9F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E2A9F3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5A9F2"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5A9E1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5A9D0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5A9BC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#E6E6E6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#F78181"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F79F81"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7BE81"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F5DA81"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F3F781"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D8F781"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BEF781"></td>
                <td bgColor="#9FF781"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81F781"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81F79F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81F7BE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81F7D8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81F7F3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81DAF5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#81BEF7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#819FF7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8181F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#9F81F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BE81F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DA81F5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F781F3"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F781D8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F781BE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7819F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D8D8D8"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#FA5858"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FA8258"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FAAC58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7D358"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F4FA58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D0FA58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#ACFA58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#82FA58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58FA58"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58FA82"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58FAAC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58FAD0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58FAF4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58D3F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#58ACFA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5882FA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5858FA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8258FA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#AC58FA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D358F7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FA58F4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FA58D0"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FA58AC"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FA5882"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BDBDBD"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#FE2E2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE642E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE9A2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FACC2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#F7FE2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#C8FE2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#9AFE2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#64FE2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2EFE2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2EFE64"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2EFE9A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2EFEC8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2EFEF7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2ECCFA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2E9AFE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2E64FE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2E2EFE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#642EFE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#9A2EFE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#CC2EFA"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE2EF7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE2EC8"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE2E9A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FE2E64"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A4A4A4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#FF0000"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF4000"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF8000"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FFBF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FFFF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BFFF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#80FF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#40FF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00FF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00FF40"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00FF80"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00FFBF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00FFFF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#00BFFF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0080FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0040FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0000FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#4000FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8000FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#BF00FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF00FF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF00BF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF0080"></td>
                <td bgColor="#FF0040"></td>
                <td bgColor="#848484"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#DF0101"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF3A01"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF7401"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DBA901"></td>
                <td bgColor="#D7DF01"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A5DF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#74DF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3ADF00"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01DF01"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01DF3A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01DF74"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01DFA5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01DFD7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#01A9DB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0174DF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#013ADF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0101DF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3A01DF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#7401DF"></td>
                <td bgColor="#A901DB"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF01D7"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF01A5"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF0174"></td>
                <td bgColor="#DF013A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#6E6E6E"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#B40404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B43104"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B45F04"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B18904"></td>
                <td bgColor="#AEB404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#86B404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5FB404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#31B404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#04B404"></td>
                <td bgColor="#04B431"></td>
                <td bgColor="#04B45F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#04B486"></td>
                <td bgColor="#04B4AE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0489B1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#045FB4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0431B4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0404B4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3104B4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5F04B4"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8904B1"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B404AE"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B40486"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B4045F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#B40431"></td>
                <td bgColor="#585858"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#8A0808"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A2908"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A4B08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#886A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#868A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#688A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#4B8A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#298A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#088A08"></td>
                <td bgColor="#088A29"></td>
                <td bgColor="#088A4B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#088A68"></td>
                <td bgColor="#088A85"></td>
                <td bgColor="#086A87"></td>
                <td bgColor="#084B8A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#08298A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#08088A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#29088A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#4B088A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#6A0888"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A0886"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A0868"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A084B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#8A0829"></td>
                <td bgColor="#424242"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#610B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#61210B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#61380B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5F4C0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#5E610B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#4B610B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#38610B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#21610B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B610B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B6121"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B6138"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B614B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B615E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B4C5F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3861"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B2161"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B0B61"></td>
                <td bgColor="#210B61"></td>
                <td bgColor="#380B61"></td>
                <td bgColor="#4C0B5F"></td>
                <td bgColor="#610B5E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#610B4B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#610B38"></td>
                <td bgColor="#610B21"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2E2E2E"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#3B0B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B170B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B240B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3A2F0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#393B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2E3B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#243B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#173B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3B0B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3B17"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3B24"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3B2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B3B39"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B2F3A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B243B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B173B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B0B3B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#170B3B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#240B3B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2F0B3A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B0B39"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B0B2E"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B0B24"></td>
                <td bgColor="#3B0B17"></td>
                <td bgColor="#1C1C1C"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#2A0A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A120A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A1B0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#29220A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#292A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#222A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#1B2A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#122A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2A0A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2A12"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2A1B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2A22"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2A29"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A2229"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A1B2A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A122A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0A0A2A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#120A2A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#1B0A2A"></td>
                <td bgColor="#220A29"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A0A29"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A0A22"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A0A1B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#2A0A12"></td>
                <td bgColor="#151515"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgColor="#190707"></td>
                <td bgColor="#190B07"></td>
                <td bgColor="#191007"></td>
                <td bgColor="#181407"></td>
                <td bgColor="#181907"></td>
                <td bgColor="#141907"></td>
                <td bgColor="#101907"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B1907"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071907"></td>
                <td bgColor="#07190B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071910"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071914"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071918"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071418"></td>
                <td bgColor="#071019"></td>
                <td bgColor="#070B19"></td>
                <td bgColor="#070719"></td>
                <td bgColor="#0B0719"></td>
                <td bgColor="#100719"></td>
                <td bgColor="#140718"></td>
                <td bgColor="#190718"></td>
                <td bgColor="#190714"></td>
                <td bgColor="#190710"></td>
                <td bgColor="#19070B"></td>
                <td bgColor="#000000"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to halt your code until the DOM is ready.
Or else the code starts to add an event listener to something that is not there.

This you can do by adding a function that is called when the body is loaded.
I've done this to your code below.

Setting CSS3 properties from javascript isn't as easy as setting CSS properties.
Not all browsers support all features, so you need to check that it is supported first.
We need to check both for webkit and moz.

To check for the transformProperty you could do something like

```
        function getCSS3TransformSupport(){
            if (undefined!==document.documentElement.style.webkitTransform){
                return "webkit";
            }
            else if (undefined!==document.documentElement.style.mozTransform){
                return "moz";
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        var supportsCSSTransform=getCSS3TransformSupport();
```

This will give you `'webkit'` or `'moz'` if the browser supports it. If it doesn't it returns `false`.

Now, if you want to change the CSS property, you have to consider if it's `webkit` or `moz`.
So the `target.style.transform` would be either `target.style.webkitTransform` or `target.style.mozTransform`.

For more info about styling CSS3 with javascript, and my source in this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                #colorchart {
                    position: fixed;
                    width:250px;
                    height:250px;
                    padding:0px;
                    margin:0px;
                    left:0px;
                    top:350px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
            <body onload="initialize();">
                <script type="text/javascript">

                function getCSS3TransformSupport(){
                    if (undefined!==document.documentElement.style.webkitTransform){
                        return "webkit";
                    }
                    else if (undefined!==document.documentElement.style.mozTransform){
                        return "moz";
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var supportsCSSTransform=getCSS3TransformSupport();


                function initialize(){
                    var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');
                    table.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                        var target = event.target||event.srcElement;
                        if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
                            var transformTo="scale(2,2)";
                            switch (supportsCSSTransform){
                                case 'moz':
                                    target.style.mozTransform=transformTo;
                                break;
                                case 'webkit':
                                    target.style.webkitTransform=transformTo;
                                break;
                            }


                            target.addEventListener ("click", function(event) {
                                var newTarget=event.target;
                                if (newTarget.tagName=='TD') {
                                    alert(newTarget.bgColor);
                                }
                            }, false);
                        }
                    }, false);
                }

                </script>
                <table id="colorchart"  >
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#FBEFEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBF2EF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBF5EF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBF8EF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBFBEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8FBEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5FBEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F2FBEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFFBEF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFFBF2"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFFBF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFFBF8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFFBFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFF8FB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFF5FB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFF2FB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#EFEFFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F2EFFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5EFFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8EFFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBEFFB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBEFF8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBEFF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FBEFF2"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FFFFFF"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E6E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7F2E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F1F8E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E6F8E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F8E6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F8F1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0F2F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0E6F8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E6E0F8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#ECE0F8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F2E0F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E0F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E0F1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E0EC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F8E0E6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FAFAFA"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#F6CECE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6D8CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6E3CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5ECCE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5F6CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#ECF6CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E3F6CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D8F6CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEF6CE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEF6D8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEF6E3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEF6EC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEF6F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEECF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CEE3F6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CED8F6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CECEF6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D8CEF6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E3CEF6"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#ECCEF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6CEF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6CEEC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6CEE3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F6CED8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F2F2F2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5BCA9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F3E2A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E1F5A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BCF5A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9F5BC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9F5E1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9E2F3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9BCF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BCA9F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D0A9F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E2A9F3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5A9F2"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5A9E1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5A9D0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5A9BC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#E6E6E6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#F78181"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F79F81"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7BE81"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F5DA81"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F3F781"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D8F781"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BEF781"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#9FF781"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81F781"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81F79F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81F7BE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81F7D8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81F7F3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81DAF5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#81BEF7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#819FF7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8181F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#9F81F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BE81F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DA81F5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F781F3"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F781D8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F781BE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7819F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D8D8D8"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#FA5858"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FA8258"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FAAC58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7D358"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F4FA58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D0FA58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#ACFA58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#82FA58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58FA58"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58FA82"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58FAAC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58FAD0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58FAF4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58D3F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#58ACFA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5882FA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5858FA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8258FA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#AC58FA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D358F7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FA58F4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FA58D0"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FA58AC"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FA5882"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BDBDBD"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#FE2E2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE642E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE9A2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FACC2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#F7FE2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#C8FE2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#9AFE2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#64FE2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2EFE2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2EFE64"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2EFE9A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2EFEC8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2EFEF7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2ECCFA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2E9AFE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2E64FE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2E2EFE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#642EFE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#9A2EFE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#CC2EFA"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE2EF7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE2EC8"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE2E9A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FE2E64"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A4A4A4"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#FF0000"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF4000"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF8000"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FFBF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FFFF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BFFF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#80FF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#40FF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00FF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00FF40"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00FF80"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00FFBF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00FFFF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#00BFFF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0080FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0040FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0000FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#4000FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8000FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#BF00FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF00FF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF00BF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF0080"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#FF0040"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#848484"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#DF0101"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF3A01"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF7401"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DBA901"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#D7DF01"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A5DF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#74DF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3ADF00"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01DF01"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01DF3A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01DF74"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01DFA5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01DFD7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#01A9DB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0174DF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#013ADF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0101DF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3A01DF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#7401DF"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#A901DB"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF01D7"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF01A5"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF0174"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#DF013A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#6E6E6E"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#B40404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B43104"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B45F04"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B18904"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#AEB404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#86B404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5FB404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#31B404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#04B404"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#04B431"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#04B45F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#04B486"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#04B4AE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0489B1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#045FB4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0431B4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0404B4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3104B4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5F04B4"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8904B1"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B404AE"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B40486"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B4045F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#B40431"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#585858"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#8A0808"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A2908"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A4B08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#886A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#868A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#688A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#4B8A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#298A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#088A08"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#088A29"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#088A4B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#088A68"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#088A85"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#086A87"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#084B8A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#08298A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#08088A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#29088A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#4B088A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#6A0888"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A0886"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A0868"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A084B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#8A0829"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#424242"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#610B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#61210B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#61380B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5F4C0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#5E610B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#4B610B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#38610B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#21610B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B610B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B6121"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B6138"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B614B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B615E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B4C5F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3861"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B2161"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B0B61"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#210B61"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#380B61"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#4C0B5F"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#610B5E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#610B4B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#610B38"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#610B21"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2E2E2E"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#3B0B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B170B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B240B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3A2F0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#393B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2E3B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#243B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#173B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3B0B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3B17"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3B24"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3B2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B3B39"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B2F3A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B243B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B173B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B0B3B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#170B3B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#240B3B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2F0B3A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B0B39"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B0B2E"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B0B24"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#3B0B17"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#1C1C1C"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#2A0A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A120A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A1B0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#29220A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#292A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#222A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#1B2A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#122A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2A0A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2A12"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2A1B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2A22"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2A29"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A2229"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A1B2A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A122A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0A0A2A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#120A2A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#1B0A2A"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#220A29"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A0A29"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A0A22"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A0A1B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#2A0A12"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#151515"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgColor="#190707"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#190B07"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#191007"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#181407"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#181907"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#141907"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#101907"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B1907"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071907"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#07190B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071910"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071914"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071918"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071418"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#071019"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#070B19"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#070719"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#0B0719"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#100719"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#140718"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#190718"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#190714"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#190710"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#19070B"></td>
                    <td bgColor="#000000"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```